# database won't refresh when I search for a different query. -ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

ok let me try to explain this as detail as I can.

I have these different inputs.  It has passenger names, ticket numbers and rloc.
I am trying to search the passengers let's say by ticket number.
I have this search button to search into the database for the ticket number.

I got the ticket number and I am trying to find the next ticket number by clicking the next button.  It works up to this point. (these are done by using ajax)

What is making me stuck is.  If I didn't refresh the page, the database would stay to the database used when I click next.
sample if I input 111 searched the record, pull it out and I click next it'll go for record 112 then 113 with another click but without refreshing the page, I input 111 and search which still works but if I click next again it'll show the record of 114 instead of 112.

I thought it might be something about the `.on()` event for binding purpose but still not getting it right.  Can someone give me an extra eyes please?  Thank you.

**Here is my html which is really basic**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h1>Ticket search</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="update-info">
    <h3>{{$num}} files have been convert and updated.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="sub-container">
    <div class="form-field">
      <label>Ticket Number : </label>
      <input class="ticket-field" type="text" name="ticketNumber" value="" placeholder="Please enter ticket number">
    </div>
    <div class="button-field">
      <input type="submit" class="btn-search"value="Search">
      <button class="btn-update">Update</button>
      <button class="btn-prev" name="previous">PREV</button>
      <button class="btn-next" name="next">NEXT</button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="ticketHolder" value="">
  </div>
  <div id="text-field">
  </div>
</div>
```

**my js search using jquery and ajax**

```
$("div.container").on("click", ".btn-search", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var noError = true;

  var ticketNumber = $.trim($("input[name='ticketNumber']").val());

  if($.isNumeric(ticketNumber) || ticketNumber==""){
    noError = true;
  }else{
    noError = false;
    $("input[name='ticketNumber']").val('');
    alert("please enter a number");
  }

  if(noError){
    $("#text-field").empty();
    $.ajax({
      method: "post",
      url: "/search",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {ticketNumber:ticketNumber},
      success: function(data){
        if(data.length>1){
          $.each(data,function(index,item){
            $("#text-field").append("<h3 class='block-hearder'><span>"+item['dateOfFile']+"</span><span>"+item['paxName']+"</span><span>"+item['airlineName']+"</span></h3><div class='text-block'>"+item['content']+"</div>");
          });

          $( "#text-field" ).accordion( "destroy" );
          $( "#text-field" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true
          });

        }else{
          $.each(data,function(index,item){
            $("#text-field").append("<div class='text-block-single'>"+item['content']+"</div>"+"<script>");
            searchNext(item['systemName'],item['ticketNumber']);
            if(item['content'].indexOf('S') != 0){
              $('.btn-prev').button( "enable" );
              $('.btn-next').button( "enable" );
            }
          });


        }
        $("input[name='ticketNumber']").val('');
      }
    });
  }
});  //end btn-search
```

**my searchNext() for js**

```
function searchNext(systemName, ticketNumber){
  var systemName = systemName;
  var ticketNumber = Number(ticketNumber);

  // Making sure this function doesn't get called twice
  if( !this.wasRun ){
    $(".btn-next").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        url: "/next",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {systemName: systemName, ticketNumber: ticketNumber},
        success: function(data){
          $("#text-field").empty();
          $("#text-field").append("<div class='text-block-single'>"+data['content']+"</div>");
          if(data['content'].indexOf('>') > 0){
            if((ticketNumber + 1) == data['ticketNumber']){
              ticketNumber++;
              searchNext(ticketNumber, data['systemName']);
            }
          }else{
            $('.btn-next').button( "disable" );
          }

        }
      });
    });  //end btn-next
  }
  this.wasRun = true;
}  //end searchNext()
```

**in my php, my search()**

```
public function search(){
    $data = array();
    /* Check if ticket number entered is not null and is number */
    if(($_POST['ticketNumber'] != null) && (is_numeric($_POST['ticketNumber']))){
        $ticketNumber = trim($_POST['ticketNumber']);
    }else{
        $ticketNumber = "";
    }

    if(strlen($ticketNumber) == 10 ){
        $model = Document::where('ticketNumber', '=', $ticketNumber)->get();
    }else{
        $data['content'] = 'entery valid ticket number (10 numbers)';
    }

    $index = 0;
    if(sizeof($model)>0){
        foreach ($model as $key => $value) {
            $document = $value->getAttributes();
                $data[$index]['content']=$document['fileContent'];
                $data[$index]['dateOfFile']=$document['dateOfFile'];
                $data[$index]['systemName']=$document['systemName'];
                $data[$index]['ticketNumber']=$document['ticketNumber'];
            $index++;
        }

    }else{
        $data[$index]['content'] = "Sorry the document does not exist, or hasn't been update yet, please click update and try again.";
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}  //End search function
```

**in my php next() which searches the next record**

```
public function next(){
    $data = array();
    $systemName = $_POST['systemName'];
    $nextTicketNumber = $_POST['ticketNumber'] + 1;

    //used to get the nextTicketNumber if there is a sequential nextTicketNumber
    $model = Document::where('systemName', '=', $systemName)
                        ->where('ticketNumber', '=', ($nextTicketNumber))->get();

    if(sizeof($model) == 0){
        $data['content'] = 'Reached end of record';
        return json_encode($data);
    }
    //Getting all the same system number and stores the tickets in an array to find the max ticketNumber
    $getAllModel = Document::where('systemName', '=', $systemName)->get();

    $allTicketNumber = [];
    if(sizeof($getAllModel) > 0){
        foreach($getAllModel as $key => $value){
            $allTicketNumber[] = $value->ticketNumber;
        }
    }
    $maxTicketNumber = max($allTicketNumber);

    if($nextTicketNumber > $maxTicketNumber){
        $data['content'] = 'Reached end of record';
    }else{
        $data['content'] = $model[0]->fileContent;
        $data['ticketNumber'] = $model[0]->ticketNumber;
        $data['systemName'] = $model[0]->systemName;
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: The thing is `ticketNumber++;`. You cache the last ticket number. You should reset that. To the number searched.

Comment: @DOCASAREL > I thought it is the number searched. in the js search what is searched and returned by using `item['ticketNumber]'.  This is the ticket searched and returned then passing this value into the `searchNext(systemName, ticketNumber)` so when I use the ticketNumber++ it is increasing the ticket number searched ins't it?×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: Yeah, but in the next line you call `searchNext` with the ticket number counted up. And that is adding up.

Comment: @DOCASAREL sorry to bother.  I have been thinking about this for few days and not getting my head around at all.  Right after I wrote this post I just took the `searchNext()` out and made the `search` save it into a global variable instead and seem to work fine.  But I still want to try solving what's in the `searchNext()` as you mentioned. I understand what you mean but my head just wouldn't get around and able to find out how do I set that to the number searched then? I did try using `data['ticketNumber']` instead of the `ticketNumber` variable

Comment: What does it do? `searchNext(data['ticketNumber'] + 1, data['systemName']);` should work.

Comment: @DOCASAREL still the same thing happens like before. if I searched 1 and click next next and showed 3 I search 1 again I click next and the result comes back as 4 instead of 2.

Comment: Hey Dora, sorry for coming back late. You should keep this tweet of mine in mind: https://twitter.com/DOCASAREL/status/495319107336941569. You should go for the version with least code but functioning! You say, you have a clean version. Go for that.

Comment: @DOCASAREL haha got it :D